How can I convert an integer to CUDA's __half FP16 type, in a constexpr fashion?
I'm the developer of aerobus and I'm facing difficulties with half precision arithmetic.
At some point in the library, I need to convert a IntType to related FloatType (same bit count) in a constexpr function (to evaluate polynomials).
I have this function (in a larger type aerobus::i16::val<x>) :
template<typename valueType>
static constexpr valueType get() { return static_cast<valueType>(x); }

in an enclosing type.
It works well when valueType is float or double and x is int32_t or int64_t but not when valueType is __half and x is int16_t.
nvcc 12.6.r12.6 generates the following error :
../src/aerobus.h:576:55: note: ‘static constexpr valueType aerobus::i16::val<x>::get() [with valueType = __half; short int x = 64]’ is not usable as a ‘constexpr’ function because:
  576 |             static constexpr INLINED DEVICE valueType get() { return (valueType)x; }
      |                                                       ^~~
../src/aerobus.h:576:55: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘__half::__half(short int)’
In file included from cuda_fp16.cpp:1:
/usr/local/cuda-12.6/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_fp16.h:4652:25: note: ‘__half::__half(short int)’ declared here
 4652 |     __CUDA_HOSTDEVICE__ __half(const short val) { __x = __short2half_rn(val).__x; }

How can I work around that? Am I forced to implement a constexpr conversion function from int16_t to __half or not?

Seems like it, if there is no constexpr version available off the shelf. You can use std::is_constant_evaluated to avoid doing inefficient conversions at runtime.

@passerby thanks. I hoped that it existed somewhere in the cuda headers.

@PasserBy: What would you consider "off the shelf"? See my answer and the link there...

Nothing in the cuda_fp16.hpp header has constexpr in it, so you'll have to do the hard work yourself.
The following compiles for me (with cuda 12.5.1 at least and options --expt-relaxed-constexpr and -std=c++20):
static constexpr unsigned short my_internal_float2half(const float f, unsigned int& sign, unsigned int& remainder) {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int u;
    unsigned int result;
    x = std::bit_cast<int>(f); //c++20 
    ////(void)std::memcpy(&x, &f, sizeof(f)); //not constexpr
    u = (x & 0x7fffffffU);
    sign = ((x >> 16U) & 0x8000U);
    // NaN/+Inf/-Inf
    if (u >= 0x7f800000U) {
        remainder = 0U;
        result = ((u == 0x7f800000U) ? (sign | 0x7c00U) : 0x7fffU);
    } else if (u > 0x477fefffU) { // Overflows
        remainder = 0x80000000U;
        result = (sign | 0x7bffU);
    } else if (u >= 0x38800000U) { // Normal numbers
        remainder = u << 19U;
        u -= 0x38000000U;
        result = (sign | (u >> 13U));
    } else if (u < 0x33000001U) { // +0/-0
        remainder = u;
        result = sign;
    } else { // Denormal numbers
        const unsigned int exponent = u >> 23U;
        const unsigned int shift = 0x7eU - exponent;
        unsigned int mantissa = (u & 0x7fffffU);
        mantissa |= 0x800000U;
        remainder = mantissa << (32U - shift);
        result = (sign | (mantissa >> shift));
        result &= 0x0000FFFFU;
    }
    return static_cast<unsigned short>(result);
}

static constexpr __half my_float2half_rn(const float a) {
    __half val;
    __half_raw r;
    unsigned int sign = 0U;
    unsigned int remainder = 0U;
    r.x = my_internal_float2half(a, sign, remainder);
    if ((remainder > 0x80000000U) || ((remainder == 0x80000000U) && ((r.x & 0x1U) != 0U))) {
        r.x++;
    }
    val = std::bit_cast<__half>(r); //allowed, see operator= for __raw_half -> __half
    return val;
}

static constexpr __half my_int2half_rn(const int i) {
    __half h;
        // double-rounding is not a problem here: if integer
        // has more than 24 bits, it is already too large to
        // be represented in half precision, and result will
        // be infinity.
        const float  f = static_cast<float>(i);
    h = my_float2half_rn(f);
    return h;
}

__device__ consteval __half convert_int16_to_half(int16_t i) {
    return my_float2half_rn(static_cast<float>(i));
}

#ifdef INSIDE_OPS_CLASS_DEF
//in your class header
template<typename VT>
static constexpr VT get() { 
    static_assert(std::is_same<int16_t, decltype(this->x)>::value);
    if constexpr (std::is_same<VT, __half>::value) {
        return convert_int16_to_half(this->x);
    } else {
        return static_cast<valueType>(x); 
    }
}
#endif
 

Note that outside of consteval, you'll want to use the built-in version, as they use a single assembly statement, letting the GPU do the conversion.
Do note that if you are worried about efficiency you really should not be mucking about with a single __half, but process them in pairs instead.

whoa this is splendid. I'll try that.

I took this and slightly modified it in aerobus. See latest commit https://github.com/aerobus-open-source/aerobus/commit/3495f2c6f9f239bee114e8ed722a22f99cb05d49#diff-d03250a3608dca3f6c4bb8ef7f981bd1c2198261d16f57bad788f3218f9df785

@RegisPortalez, that's a massive commit :-).

If you can separate the host-side and device-side implementations (which you can - at the very least using #ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__ and such) - and your host-side compiler support C++23, you can convert integers to a half-precision type the usual way. Example:
#include <stdfloat>

constexpr std::float16_t magic(std::int16_t x)
{
    return static_cast<std::float16_t>(x);
}

this works with GCC, not with clang it seems (GodBolt). Of course, you'll need to reinterprest std::float16_t as __half, which is not constexpr, but you can leave that for runtime, not compile-time.
Other things to try:

Use an existing, established, implementation of this conversion which can be marked constexpr. Johan's answer offered his own; but you could also consider the FP16 library on GitHub which is intended for exactly these purposes and is rather popular. Here's the relevant function, int2half.
If you're able  can manage to up-cast to float in a constexpr way (again, that needs checking, e.g. for clang, MSVC), you can use your compiler's constexpr int-to-float conversion
File a bug with NVIDIA about this. Not an immediate solution, but pressure from users may get them to offer us constexpr fp16 functions.


I have no option for runtime in this part of the library. But I will file a bug with NVIDIA for sure.

@RegisPortalez: If this part of the library is not used at runtime, then perhaps you should drop cuda_fp16.hpp and use either the C++ standard std::float16_t or the compiler's built-in FP16 type (_Float16 in GCC for example)

The problem with the FP16 library is that it's c++11. You'll need to rewrite it, same as the cuda_fp16 header.

Opened a bug with NVIDIA : https://developer.nvidia.com/bugs/4863696
